# Novikov's theorem for time-independent functional

Tags: quantum-mechanics, stochastic-processes, noise

$\textbf{Introduction}$

Given a Gaussian-colored noise

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &\langle z(t)\rangle=0,\\
    &\langle z(t)z(t')\rangle=C(t-t').\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
A given stochastic differential equation follows
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\rho_z}(t)=-i[\mathcal{H}_0,\rho_z]-i[z(t)\mathcal{H}_1,\rho_z],
\end{equation}
where is equation is per trajectory. The stochastic average is then $\rho(t)=\langle \rho_z(t)\rangle$. The differential equation for the average then is
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\rho}(t)=-i[\mathcal{H}_0,\rho]-i[\mathcal{H}_1,\langle z(t)\rho_z\rangle].
\end{equation}

Then, it all boils down to calculating $\langle z(t)\rho_z\rangle$. For this, the general procedure is to use the Novikov's theorem
\begin{equation}
    \langle z(t) M_t[z] \rangle=\langle z(t)\rangle \langle M_t[z] \rangle+\int_0^t  dt'\langle z(t) z(t') \rangle \langle \frac{\delta M_{t'}[z]}{\delta z(t')} \rangle
\end{equation}
where $M_t[z]$ is a functional of z. In this case,
$M_t[z]=\rho_z(t)$ and the functional derivative is

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \rho_z}{\delta z}=\frac{\partial \dot{\rho_z}}{\partial z}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \dot{\rho_z}}{\partial \dot{z}}=-i[\mathcal{H}_1,\rho_z]
\end{equation}
Finally,
\begin{equation}
    \langle z(t) \rho_z \rangle=-i\int_0^t dt' C(t-t')[\mathcal{H}_1,\rho(t')]
\end{equation}

$\textbf{Question}$

This procedure seems only to work if the functional is time-dependent, i.e, $M_t[z]=\rho_z(t)$. It is confusing to me to understand how to proceed with this other stochastic equation

\begin{equation}
    \dot{\rho_z}(t)=-i[\mathcal{H}_0,\rho_z]-i[z(t)\mathcal{H}_1,\rho^0],
\end{equation}
where now $\rho^0$ is a time-independent object. Naively, if I proceed as before, but now with $M_t[z]=\rho^0$,
\begin{equation}
    \langle z(t) \rho^0 \rangle=\int_0^t  dt'\langle z(t) z(t') \rangle \langle \frac{\rho^0}{\delta z(t')} \rangle
\end{equation}
This functional derivative seems to be 0.

Comment: If $\rho_0$ functional of $z(t)$, than it should depend on $z(t)$, which make sit time-dependent (although it may not contain the explicit time dependence.) Could you give reference to the source/text that you are using?

Comment: Maybe it is wrong to consider $\rho_0$ as a functional... The introduction is based on: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/134/10001/pdf (from Eq. 1 to 6). I would like to apply this to the results of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.02916.pdf (Eq. 1 and 10, and Appendix A).

Comment: It is not quite clear to me where the equation with $\rho^0$ comes from - it seems like a perturbation treatment... while Furutsu-Novikov is used to obtain a closed equation (it makes a Gaussian approximation, but it is non-pertuirbative.)

Comment: If you don't get an answer in the next couple of days, you might want to try over at [math.se]